# Combining two tuples into one in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a bunch of letters grouped together and I want to find out which pair bonds with another the most, as an example I have

```
 a   b   d    b 
 b   c   e    a
```

and it should return ab or ba because a-b are the most occurred here.

so far I have made a query that just pulls every two letters that are together, but when I run the query I get something like the above example but all are in separate tuples, like this

```
 a 
 b

 b
 c

 d
 e

 b 
 a
```

I need to compare the occurence of all the PAIRS, my logic so far is that I can use nvl() to concat them(but nvl() of a-b and b-a returns two separate instances), then run a count, but I'm not sure how to run a count on these as I called the letters

```
select a.value, b.value
from Letter a, Letter b, Word aw, Word bw, Sentence senA, sentence senb
where a.id = aw.aid and aw.pid = sena.id and b.id = bw.aid and 
bw.pid = senb.id and aw.pid = bw.pid and a.value != b.value 
;
```

TL;DR: I want to do a count(a.ltr-b.ltr pair) but not sure how to code that.

Thanks!

EDIT: table structure:

```
letter(id, value)
        \
   word(aid, pid)
              \
     sentence(id, name,sid)
```

basically, if two letters end up in the same sentence.id, they are a pair(bond).

Comment: Can you share your table(s) structure(s) please?

Comment: Share the Query which is giving you the Pair Occurences in the **SECOND CODE BLOCK** you've shown.